# Two solutions with min max values - which should be slower?

Tags: java, performance, array, integer, comparative-review

While practicing at codinbat.com on the [assignment](http://codingbat.com/prob/p196640):

> Given an array length 1 or more of `int`s, return the difference between the largest and smallest values in the array. Note: the built-in `Math.min(v1, v2)` and `Math.max(v1, v2)` methods return the smaller or larger of two values.

I wrote a solution (1):

```
public int bigDiff(int[] nums)
{
    int min = nums[0];
    int max = nums[0];    

    for (int i = 1 ; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] < min)
        {
            min = nums[i];
        }
        if (nums[i] > max)
        {
            max = nums[i];
        }        
    }

    return max - min;  
}
```

You can see it has no `Math.min` or `Math.max` calls. So then I rewrote the solution to see how it looks with `Math.min` and `Math.max`:

```
public int bigDiff(int[] nums)
{
    int min = nums[0];
    int max = nums[0];    

    for (int i = 1 ; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        min = Math.min(nums[i],min);
        max = Math.max(nums[i],max);
    }

    return max - min;  
}
```

The solution became a little shorter, but I think it makes unnecessary assignments when going through the array.

Is solution (2) in general slower than solution (1)?

Comment: Before doing any benchmark, I reckon you should retrieve `nums[i]` only once. Also, if you want to perform tiny optimisations, you can keep in mind the fact that if a value is smaller than the min, it will not be bigger than the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unnecessary assignments are extra instructions when the code is executed. So *in theory*, the second solution should be generally slower. In practice this difference may not even be measurable.

More importantly, [@Josay](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9452/josay)'s comment is spot on that your first solution can be optimized, considering that `nums[i]` cannot be smaller than `min` and greater than `max` at the same time:

```
if (nums[i] < min) {
    min = nums[i];
} else if (nums[i] > max) {
    max = nums[i];
}
```

Now it's not just a matter of different number of assignment instructions, this solution makes fewer comparisons, so it's clearly more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: those solutions are identical performance-wise. There is no "magic" in `Min` or `Max` methods: they do the same thing you do in your first solution - compare the two values using `if` operator. There is no significant performance cost for a method call or for an extra assignment - those operations are so cheap, that you won't solve any real-life performance issue with this kind of optimization. If you will become obsessed with those small things - it will have a negative effect on your code quality. So, instead of asking, which is faster, you should ask yourself which is more *clean*, *readable* and *OOP*-ish. I would go with second solution.

If you want to *really* speed things up - you should first identify the *real* problem. In your example - it is the number of iterations, not the number of assignments. So the *faster* solution would probably involve multi-threading and iterating through different parts of your array simultaneously.

Comment: Agree with the first part of your answer. But, does threading help at all when there is no 'wait' involved?

Comment: @Teddy, what do you mean?

Comment: Considering that thread initializing and management takes resources (not to mention changing the algorithm), I think multi-threading would become worth while if array contains about 10000 elements?

Comment: @Teddy, There are certain optimizations that can be made, but generally yes, for simple operations over small arrays multithreading is not worthwhile. I can't tell you if its 100000 elements or 100 elements in this case though. My point was that IF you need optimization in this case, then you probably have a really large array.